# Forn Validation ignored with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that uses an AJAX call to submit the info to Google Sheets which is working fine except when I try to add form validation. Then it is just running the AJAX call.

Below is my HTML Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MooWoos Stall Booking</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--build:css css/styles.min.css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <!--endbuild-->

</head>

<body>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
        <a class="logo"><img src="assets/logo_opt.png"></a>
    </nav>

    <hr>

    <div class="modal fade" id="redirect_page" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <div id="user_msg" align="left">Booking successful! Redirecting to PayPal... </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 bookingform">
            <h1>Stall Booking Form</h1>
            <p class="lead">
                Fill out the form to book and pay for your stall!
            </p>
            <form id="bookingForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" title="Please enter your name" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address: </label>
                    <textarea name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Address" value="" title="Please enter your address"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Telephone Number: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Telephone Number" value="" title="Please enter the best telephone number to contact you on"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" value="" title="Please enter your Email address"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date">Which date would you like to book?: </label>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="13th September" /> Sunday 13th September</p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="6th February" /> Saturday 6th February</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>What type of stall do you require?</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Preloved" value="Preloved">
                        <label for="stallType-Preloved">Preloved</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="c-rail">Will you be bringing a clothes rail?: </label>
                            <input type="radio" name="c-rail" value="Yes" /> Yes
                            <input type="radio" name="c-rail" value="No" /> No
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Craft" value="Craft">
                        <label for="stallType-Craft">Craft</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="craftName">What name do you use?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="craftName" name="craftName" class="require-if-active" placeholder="Craft Name" title="Please provide us with your Craft name" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Business" value="Business">
                        <label for="stallType-Business">Business</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="bizName">What is your business name?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="bizName" name="bizName" class="require-if-active" placeholder="Business Name" title="Please provide us with your Business name" value="" />
                            <label for="insurance">Do you have Public Liability Insurance?</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="insurance" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="We will require proof of this prior to market day" value="Yes"/> Yes
                            <input type="radio" id="insurance" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="Our insurance does not cover other businesses. Please ensure you have adequate cover and provide us with proof prior to market day" value="No"/> No
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="button" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Book & Pay" />
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; MooWoos 2018. Website by Luke Brewerton</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </footer>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!--build:js js/mwbookings-min.js -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.serialize-object.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>
</html>
```

And my JS file:

```
var $form = $('form#bookingForm'),
    url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwaEsXX1iK8nNkkvL57WCYHJCtMAbXlfSpSn3rsJj2spRi-41Y/exec'

function validateForm() {
    var errorMessage="";
    var name=document.forms["bookingForm"]["name"].value;
    if (name==null ||name==""){
        errorMessage = "Your Name is required.\
        ";
    }

    if (errorMessage !=""){
        alert(errorMessage);
        return false;
    }
}

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $form.serializeObject(),
        success: function () {
            $('#redirect_page').modal('show');
            window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000);
        }
    });
});
```

I have a sneaky feeling that I need to do my form validation within the submit function before the AJAX call but I am new to using JS to do this, previously I have used PHP to do it all.

Comment: You're not calling `validateForm()` from anywhere..? It also seems rather pointless sending an AJAX request when all you do is refresh the page when it completes.

Comment: Where would I call this? in the submit function?

Comment: That would make the most sense. Just ensure you check the response from the function call before you send the AJAX.

Comment: That makes sense. I'l ltry that! It currently reloads as it will redirect to PayPal when I get to that point, I put in the refresh when I was writing the AJAX call so I didnt have to keep manually reloading everytime I submitted the form.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll add an answer for you as there's a couple of things you can do to improve the code in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you aren't calling the `validateForm()` function anywhere. You need to call that before the form is submit in order to check its validity.

You should also use a `type="submit"` button within your form for accessibility reasons. This will also allow users to submit the form by pressing the return key while a field is in focus. You can then hook to the `submit` event to handle the form submission. Try this:

```
<form id="bookingForm">
  <!-- form fields... -->

  <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Book & Pay" />
</form>
```

```js
function validateForm() {
  var errorMessage = "";
  var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
  if (name == null || name == "") {
    errorMessage = "Your Name is required.\n";
  }
  return errorMessage;
}

$form.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var error = validateForm();
  if (error) {
    alert(error);
    return;
  }

  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    // ajax request...
  });
});
```

You should however note that in most browsers the `required` attribute will achieve this logic for you without the need for any JS intervention.

Comment: I did try using the HTML5 required attribute but that seems to have no effect

Answer (score 0):

```
var $form = $('form#bookingForm'),
url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwaEsXX1iK8nNkkvL57WCYHJCtMAbXlfSpSn3rsJj2spRi-41Y/exec'

function validateForm() {
var errorMessage="";
var name=document.forms["bookingForm"]["name"].value;
if (name==null ||name==""){
    errorMessage = "Your Name is required.\
    ";
return true;
}

if (errorMessage !=""){
    alert(errorMessage);
    return false;
}
}

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
//e.preventDefault();

var res = validateForm();
if(res != false) {

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject(),
    success: function () {
        $('#redirect_page').modal('show');
        window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000);
    }
});
} else {
//handle else condition however u want
}
});
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for editing it, however some description of what the issue is and why your code helps would educate the OP for future occurences.

Comment: Thank you.Sure i will provide  some descriptions for future answers.

Comment: @Kiran Your answer doesn't contain an explanation to what you have done, why it will work and what the problem was in the OP code. Please edit and show an explanation.